# Wordpress multiple featured image hover help needed (php/jquery) - think I'm 80% there

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, hover

I wanted to have the featured header images in my blog posts change to alternative images on hover - all of my header images are black and white so the idea is to have them change to high contrast monotone versions when hovering...

I followed the guidance of [**this tutorial**](http://www.scratchinginfo.net/hover-two-featured-images-wordpress-via-multiple-post-thumbnails-plugin/), and after a few bumps in the road I'm now at the final hurdle where I add some javascript within the head tag of a primary php file in order to generate the hovering image transition.

Unfortunately it does absolutely nothing - I've tried placing the code in various other places (including other primary php files), with no success. Since my coding knowledge is quite basic and only within the realms of html/css, I'm really not sure what else I can try to get this working...

Unfortunately the demo link within the original tutorial I followed is dead so I can't pull apart any working code either!

[**this is my blog**](http://lowe.so/) - I've temporarily removed display:none on the alternative image, just to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do. The following is the javascript code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//Get the total number of elements having the class "galery"
var getTotalElements = jQuery(".gallery").length;

//Running Loop
for(var i = 1; i <= getTotalElements; i++) {
jQuery('.post'+i).on('hover', createCallback(i) );
jQuery('.post'+i).on('mouseleave', createCallback1(i) );
}

//This method is for hover function
function createCallback( i ){
return function(){
jQuery('.post'+i+' .entry-header .FirstImage'+i).hide();
jQuery('.post'+i+' .entry-header .SecondImage'+i).show();
}
}

//This method is for mouseleave function.
function createCallback1( i ){
return function(){
jQuery('.post'+i+' .entry-header .FirstImage'+i).show();
jQuery('.post'+i+' .entry-header .SecondImage'+i).hide();
}
}

});
</script>
```

The following is the code I've included in my content php file, which calls on both featured images:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div  class="first_image FirstImage"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
<div class="second_image SecondImage"><?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'colored-image', get_the_ID()); ?></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First modify the script to something like this instead.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('[class^="post"]').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var flag = e.type === 'mouseenter';
        $('.entry-header .FirstImage', this).toggle(!flag);
        $('.entry-header .SecondImage', this).toggle(flag);
    });

});
```

Then you have to actually include the script **after** jQuery.
Right now you have the script in the header, and jQuery is loaded in the footer, so jQuery isn't available when the script is loaded.

In Wordpress, you should generally put the script in a seperate file, and enqueue it with [**`wp_enqueue_script`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

It should be noted that just a straight swap like this could probably be done with just CSS as well

```
.post:hover .entry-header .FirstImage {
    display: none;
}

.post:hover .entry-header .SecondImage {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Oh my days! I've been trying to crack the jQuery thing all day - just put in your css code and it works a treat! Thanks so much. The other post headers are now acting up when I hover but I think it's just because I haven't actually uploaded the alternative versions to them  yet...

Comment: I looked at them, and the second image is missing, so they just dissapear for me. I didn't really test the CSS, but you should be able to tweak the selectors, add a class etc. if you need to be more specific.

Comment: Yeah all the other header images are disappearing on hover for me too. I thought it might've been because I hadn't actually uploaded any more of the alternatives, but I just uploaded the alternative for the second post (the troubadour image) and its still disappearing...Aah man! Well at least I know now it's possible with CSS...

Comment: Alright fixed! It was my mistake - I'd selected the second alternative image using an old plugin I was trying out earlier today! Selected it using the correct one and it works. Thanks a lot for the help, it's made the wasted day a little better.